# Count combinations by column, order doesn't matter

Tags: r, combinations

```
dat <- data.frame(A = c("r","t","y","g","r"),
                  B = c("g","r","r","t","y"),
                  C = c("t","g","t","r","t"))

  A B C
1 r g t
2 t r g
3 y r t
4 g t r
5 r y t
```

I would like to list the characters that occur together across the three columns, ignoring order.
e.g.

```
Combinations  Freq
r t g         3
y t r         2
```

If I wanted to add a frequency count of a nominal variable (e.g. gender), how might I do that?

e.g.

```
dat <- data.frame(A = c("r","t","y","g","r"),
                  B = c("g","r","r","t","y"),
                  C = c("t","g","t","r","t"),
             Gender = c("male", "female", "female", "male", "male"))

dat

  A B C Gender
1 r g t   male
2 t r g female
3 y r t female
4 g t r   male
5 r y t   male
```

To get this:

```
Combinations  Freq   Male   Female
r t g         3      2       1
y t r         2      1       1
```

Comment: The etiquette here is usually to not make major edits to a question after answers have been posted unless the answerers are expecting it. Btw, your formatting for the new stuff is a little off. Indent four spaces to make code blocks, or highlight and press CTRL+K. You're using inline code formatting there.

Comment: Apologies. I am new to this. Thanks for the tip. I didn't know how to go about asking the follow-up, I was using this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10243/asking-a-follow-up-question as a guide. Also, I may have accidentally removed your answer to the follow-up, I'll try to fix that.

Comment: Yeah, good find there. I agree with Shog's "If the answer to a follow-up question could easily be worked into an existing answer, then it should be asked in a comment and answered via an edit to that answer." The problem is that you cannot really know whether the extension is easy or not (otherwise you wouldn't need to ask about it :) ). So, I would err on the side of polling all answerers, and if any says "nope, I don't want to edit for that", then consider making a new question instead, since your edit will make existing answers invalid/incomplete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do...

```
data.frame(table(combo = sapply(split(as.matrix(dat), row(dat)), 
  function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=" "))))

  combo Freq
1 g r t    3
2 r t y    2
```

For readability, I'd suggest doing it in multiple lines and/or using magrittr:

```
d = as.matrix(dat)
library(magrittr)

d %>% split(., row(.)) %>% sapply(
  . %>% sort %>% paste(collapse = " ")
) %>% table(combo = .) %>% data.frame

  combo Freq
1 g r t    3
2 r t y    2
```

---

Re the edit / new question, I'd take a somewhat different approach, maybe like...

```
# new example data
dat <- data.frame(A = c("r","t","y","g","r"), B = c("g","r","r","t","y"), C = c("t","g","t","r","t"),Gender = c("male", "female", "female", "male", "male"))

library(data.table)
setDT(dat)

dat[, combo := sapply(transpose(.SD), 
  . %>% sort %>% paste(collapse = " ")), .SDcols=A:C]

dat[, c(
  n = .N, 
  Gender %>% factor(levels=c("male", "female")) %>% table %>% as.list
), by=combo]

   combo n male female
1: g r t 3    2      1
2: r t y 2    1      1
```

Comment: btw, I just ran the first solution you provided (data.frame) on the `dat` frame that included the variable gender, and it simply coerced the variable into the output and provided the answer to the second question. So, in essence you killed two birds with one stone!

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  pmap_dfr(~list(...)[order(c(...))] %>% set_names(names(dat))) %>%
  group_by_all %>% 
  count

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
# # Groups:   A, B, C [2]
#   A     B     C         n
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 g     r     t         3
# 2 r     t     y         2
```